Need help removing specific series in LiveCharts custom ToolTip based on Data.Point values
I basically need to remove all the series where the data point is NaN. Here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like
this
Ideally the only series I want displayed are the ones with actual values.
Here's the code i used for the custom tool tip:
public partial class StockToolTip : IChartTooltip
{
    private TooltipData _data;

    public StockToolTip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TooltipData Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

   

    public TooltipSelectionMode? SelectionMode { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

And here's the XAML:
<UserControl x:Class="Stock_Software.StockToolTip"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Points}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Series.Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Y, StringFormat={}{0} SQM}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

I've tried filtering data points based on this post: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/issues/315
But can't figure out how to return them points as it's all readonly.
Any help would be appreciated!

Is this WinForms or WPF? In any case, LiveCharts is now LiveCharts2, you should use that if you're not -- Make it clear whether this is WinForms or WPF, change the tag in case it's actually the latter

This is in winforms, and yeah pretty sure it's using LiveCharts not LiveCharts2 as I haven't had time to switch just yet.

The key "word" is "series". It's ONE "collection" of data points that is "added" to a chart in order to display it on that chart.

How do I filter out the series on the ToolTip class? Data.Points has the point series inside it and I want to filtered out specific ones. I tried using this code: var filteredPoints = Data.Points.Where(x => x.Series.Title != "my series title to ignore"); but I can't actually assign the Data or Data.Points because it's read-only.
